# Why does re-applying filter in Excel 2013 takes the cursor to the start of the document?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sheet with columns through A to J, running into thousands of rows. When i try to reapply a filter, first by removing the filter and re-applying it again, excel changes the view of the document, taking it to the first cell.

Why is it doing that?

Is there a way around this, because its cumbersome to come back to the cell again ( i click a right and left to come back to the cell again), but most importantly, it distracts you and puts you off focus.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say "first by removing the filter and re-applying it again." For example: Are you clicking the "Reapply" button in the "Sort & Filter" section in the Data tab? Are you enabling then re-enabling data filtering? Are you checking then re-checking particular values in the drop-down for one of the filtered columns?

Comment: I am re-enabling data filtering